# how to start stacked bars from a negative value?

Tags: dimple.js

I am trying to create a stacked bars chart in dimple.js with the stacked bar starting from a negative position.

Is there any property of the chart that does this or is there any tweak that we can put into dimple.js file?

Answer (score 0):

That's a slightly unusual requirement and dimple doesn't support it as a simple property, however you can create the impression of a bar starting below zero by using a fake axis.  Here's an example with accompanying fiddle to show what I mean:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 600, 400);
var data = [
    { bar: "A", value: "100" },
    { bar: "B", value: "110" },
    { bar: "C", value: "120" },
    { bar: "D", value: "130" }
    ];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "bar");
var y1 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "My Fake Axis Title");
var y2 = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "value");
y1.overrideMin = -100;
y1.overrideMax = 200;
y2.overrideMin = -10;
y2.hidden = true;
chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar, [x, y2]);
chart.draw();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LVKfa/1/