# rCharts (dimple) area chart with negative series

Tags: r, rcharts, dimple.js

I have the following problem; I am using the rCharts wrapper around dimple to produce an area chart. I realized when I add a series with negative values (v3), the chart series colour and the legend are different. Below is the following code;

```
library(rCharts)
library(reshape2)
seq(as.Date("2011-3-1"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
df <- data.frame(date= 2003:2014,
            v1 = runif(12,100,700), 
            v2 = runif(12,10,70) ,
            v3 = -1*runif(12,3,15))
dat <- melt(df,id="date")
dat$date <- as.character(dat$date)
p <- dPlot(value ~ date,
      groups = "variable",
      data = dat,
      type = "area")
p$legend( x = 60, y = 10, width = 620, height = 20,
      horizontalAlign = "right")
p
```

[image]

I would appreciate it if you can help.

Comment: Negative values really are not supported by dimple in stacked area http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673476/how-to-start-stacked-bars-from-a-negative-value.  I would suggest that negative values would be better represented by another chart form

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Can someone please, direct me to a package, which allows for negative values with interactive features?